# How can I use ffmpeg to mute only 2 channels?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mute

How can I use ffmpeg to mute only 2 channels (5,6) in the video that have 8 channels of audio? I already used `-filter_complex, -map_channel` but was unsuccessful.

I tried using this command only one stream audio, but all channels were muted:

`ffmpeg -i original.mxf -filter_complex "[0:5]volume=enable='between(t,1,300)':volume=0[a1]" -map 0:v -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map "[a1]" -map 0:6 -map 0:7 -map 0:8 -c:v copy -c:a:1 pcm_s16le -b:a 320k convertido.mxf` 
See below input file:

```
ffprobe original.mxf -v error -show_format -show_streams -print_format json
```

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mpeg2video",
            "codec_long_name": "MPEG-2 video",
            "profile": "4:2:2",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "coded_width": 0,
            "coded_height": 0,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "film_grain": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 1,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv422p",
            "level": 2,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "chroma_location": "topleft",
            "field_order": "tt",
            "refs": 1,
            "r_frame_rate": "30000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "30000/1001",
            "time_base": "1001/30000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 630,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "50000000",
            "extradata_size": 22,
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            },
            "side_data_list": [
                {
                    "side_data_type": "CPB properties",
                    "max_bitrate": 50000000,
                    "min_bitrate": 0,
                    "avg_bitrate": 0,
                    "buffer_size": 6111232,
                    "vbv_delay": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 5,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 6,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 7,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 8,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1009008,
            "duration": "21.021000",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B701"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "original.mxf",
        "nb_streams": 9,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mxf",
        "format_long_name": "MXF (Material eXchange Format)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "21.021000",
        "size": "155863121",
        "bit_rate": "59317109",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "operational_pattern_ul": "060e2b34.04010101.0d010201.01010900",
            "uid": "adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0000",
            "generation_uid": "adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0001",
            "company_name": "FFmpeg",
            "product_name": "OP1a Muxer",
            "product_version_num": "58.45.100.0.0",
            "product_version": "58.45.100",
            "product_uid": "adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0002",
            "toolkit_version_num": "58.45.100.0.0",
            "material_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D0013B7F2A652947134A9B7F2A60052947134A9B700",
            "timecode": "00:00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

This is output when ffmpeg is processing the file:

```
  Stream #0:5 (pcm_s24le) -> volume:default (graph 0)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  volume:default (graph 0) -> Stream #0:5 (pcm_s16le)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:6 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:7 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:8 -> #0:8 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
```

Comment: Does [this link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) solve the problem?

Comment: I tried using this command, but all channels were muted: 
'ffmpeg -i original.mxf -filter_complex "[0:5]volume=enable='between(t,1,300)':volume=0[a1]" -map 0:v -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map "[a1]" -map 0:6  -map 0:7 -map 0:8 -c:v copy -c:a:1 pcm_s16le -b:a 320k convertido.mxf'

Comment: Finally...
ffmpeg -v error -y -i original.mxf -map 0:v -filter_complex "[0:3]volume=enable='between(t,1,60)':volume=0[a5];[0:4]volume=enable='between(t,1,60)':volume=0[a6]" -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map [a5] -map [a6] -map 0:7 -map 0:8 convertido.mxf

Comment: Better put up an answer and later mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
ffmpeg -v error -y -i original.mxf -map 0:v -filter_complex "[0:3]volume=enable='between(t,1,60)':volume=0[a5];[0:4]volume=enable='between(t,1,60)':volume=0[a6]" -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map [a5] -map [a6] -map 0:7 -map 0:8 convertido.mxf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).